# Realtime dashboard/notification with PHP

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, pusher

I want to implement a real time notifications feature, I've looked into many things including pusher.com, socketo.me & socket.io with nodejs. I want to go for socketo.me or with nodejs+socket.io But I want this notification part separate from my current web app one more thing how user authentication will work in this case?  Please guide how to keep these two things separate with user authentication.

Comment: If the notification system is independent from the application, then the first one should not be aware of users, user authentication, etc. Thus, your notify system will push through sockets all the available info for notifying, and then, recieving it in the application layer, you should filter the things for the current users, and if there are new things - display the notification.

Comment: Notification system will access the same database and the app flow is:
User logged in -> on dashboard the user will see notifications related to some activity. The notification system needs to know which type of user is logged to send the particular types of notifications.

Comment: If you still want them decoupled, you will need to provide an interface like api, from your application, that the notification system will query to recieve info about logged users, etc.